# shadowOf() undefined in Robolectric-3.0-rc3.jar

Tags: android, robolectric

I am using Eclipse IDE with Robolectric unit test case framework (robolectric-3.0-rc3.jar) to write unit test case in android application test project.

```
MainActivity activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(MainActivity.class);
activity.findViewById(R.id.myvideoview).performClick();

Intent expectedIntent = new Intent(activity, CategoryActivity.class);
assertThat(shadowOf(activity).getNextStartedActivity()).isEqualTo(expectedIntent);
```

Comment: Do you use support activity?

Comment: @EugenMartynov no. I am not using any support activity. I have created Java project with robolectric library added and Junit 4 framework.

Comment: Why do you need robolectric for Java project?

Comment: @EugenMartynov I am using robolectric framework to write unit test case for android project so we need it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use `Shadows.shadowOf()`, it changed in Robolectric 3.0.
For further reference about other changes, see this [guide](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/wiki/2.4-to-3.0-Upgrade-Guide)

Comment: I tried Shadows.shadowOf(), but Shadows class is not exist in Robolectric-3.0-rc3.jar

Comment: It does exist, however you may not be importing it. Also, maybe the project setup is not correct. Please check your imports and setup to see if anything changes. Can you switch to Android Studio?

Comment: Shadows class does not exist in robolectric-3.0-rc3.jar. to use Shadows class we need to add another third party library called shadows-core-3.0-rc3.jar